# perl: count calls to a method while testing

Tags: perl, unit-testing, testing

I've got a test that looks like this:

```
my $mockobj = My::Module->new();
$mockobj = Test::MockObject::Extends->new($obj);

my $callcount = 0;

$mockobj->mock('Foo', sub {
  print STDERR "foo\n";
  $callcount++;
  return 1;
});

$mockobj->CallsFoo();
is($callcount, 1);
$mockobj->CallsFooTwice();
is($callcount, 3);
```

I'm wondering if there's a better way to accomplish this.  In some other languages, there are modules that are capable of monitoring the number of times a function is called (such as [sinon](http://sinonjs.org/) for javascript).  Is there such a thing for perl, or do I have to do it manually like this?

Comment: Test::MockObject allows you to record all calls to a function. You'd usually use this module, or something simpler, to completely remove dependencies in unit tests. You can use that to only do a count, while also controlling the return values.

Comment: @simbabque that's exactly what I'm doing. Are you saying this is the only way to accomplish this?

Comment: Another way would be Wrap::Sub (on CPAN) to craft a pre-execution or post-execution hook that handles counts.

Comment: Many Perl [profilers](http://metacpan.org/pod/Devel::Profile) do this, at the expense of performance.

Comment: Of course you don't HAVE to use a CPAN module; everything a module is doing can be done in code, though the barrier for XS code is pretty high, Pure Perl provide everything you need to grab a subref, create a new sub in the old sub's typeglob, and then make the new sub goto the old sub after doing its own massaging.

Comment: You can also *wrap* a method instead of *mocking* (replacing) it.